# Type error when importing pandas DataFrame from excel file in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save a pandas DataFrame as an excel file and import it again and convert it back to a dictionary. The data frame is quite large in size. For instance, consider the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

path = 'file.xlsx'
dict1 = {'a' : [3, [1, 2, 3], 'text1'],
         'b' : [4, [4, 5, 6, 7], 'text2']}
print('\n\nType 1:', type(dict1['a'][1]))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
df1.to_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')
print("\n\nSaved df:\n", df1 , '\n\n')

df2 = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1')
print("\n\nLoaded df:\n", df2 , '\n\n')

dict2 = df2.to_dict(orient='list')
print("New dict:", dict2, '\n\n')
print('Type 2:', type(dict2['a'][1]))
```

The output is:

```
Type 1: <class 'list'>


Saved df:
            a             b
0          3             4
1  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6, 7]
2      text1         text2




Loaded df:
            a             b
0          3             4
1  [1, 2, 3]  [4, 5, 6, 7]
2      text1         text2


New dict: {'a': [3, '[1, 2, 3]', 'text1'], 'b': [4, '[4, 5, 6, 7]', 'text2']}


Type 2: <class 'str'>
```

Could you help me get back the original dictionary with the same element types?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, there is an option with `read_excel` which allows us to change the `dtype` of the columns as they're read in, however there is no such option to change the `dtype` of any of the rows. So, we have to do the type conversion ourselves, after the data has been read in.

As you've shown in your question, `df['a'][1]` has type `str`, but you'd like it to have type `list`.

So, let's say we have some string `l ='[1, 2, 3]'` we could convert it to a list of ints (`l=[1, 2, 3]`) as `[int(val) for val in l.strip('[]').split(',')]`. Now, we can use this in conjunction with the `.apply` method to get what we desire:

```py
df.iloc[1] = df.iloc[1].apply(lambda x : [int(val) for val in x.strip('[]').split(',')])
```

Putting this example back together we have:

```
import pandas as pd

# Data as read in by read_excel method
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [3, '[1, 2, 3]', 'text1'],
                   'b' : [4, '[4, 5, 6, 7]', 'text2']})
print('Type: ', type(df2['a'][1]))
#Type:  <class 'str'>

# Convert strings in row 1 to lists
df2.iloc[1] = df2.iloc[1].apply(lambda x : [int(val) for val in x.strip('[]').split(',')])

print('Type: ', type(df2['a'][1]))
#Type:  <class 'list'>

dict2 = df2.to_dict(orient='list')
```